# how to simplify lst = [ x**2 for x in [x**2 for x in range(11)]] this code using for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

i'm a new learner of python. tring to write below code using for loop

```
lst = [ x**2 for x in [x**2 for x in range(11)]]
```

I tryed it this way

```
lst = []
for x in lst:
    lst.append(x)
    for x in range(0,11):
        lst.append(x)
```

but couldn't identify my mistake.
please help to solve it.

Comment: For starters there is not a single ``x**2`` in your loop. Why do you expect the two to be equivalent at all?

Comment: Do you understand what the first code is doing? If you write out what happens it might show where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is thinking there are nested loops here. The outer comprehension loops over an unnamed list created by the inner comprehension. Here I have named it `_scratch`.

```
_scratch = []
lst = []

for x in range(11):
    _scratch.append(x**2)
for x in _scratch:
    lst.append(x**2)
```

However we can see that this can be simplified, taking away the second loop

```
lst = []
for x in range(11):
    lst.append((x**2)**2)
```

And knowing some arithmetic, it can be simplified further

```
lst = []
for x in range(11):
    lst.append(x**4)
```

Comment: And returning to a list comp would look like this: `lst = [x**4 for x in range(11)]`.

Comment: @Haveaniceday indeed

Comment: thank you and I appreciate your help. can you tell me how to implement nested for loop in this code

Comment: @SoudipNath what do you mean? simply replace your code with Caleth's.

Comment: @SoudipNath to do what? There isn't a nesting of loops in the original, instead one loop after another.